# How-to install docker-compose on al2023

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker-compose

The docker documentation states the compose plugin is installed automatically with the latest docker version.
I built a new EC2 instance running al2023 and installed docker. But received this error:

```
$ docker compose --help
docker: 'compose' is not a docker command.  
$ docker --version 
Docker version 24.0.5, build ced0996
```

I'm guessing this could be a simple version problem.

Answer (score 0):

I looked around for a while before finally tracking this down.
It's here for anyone who finds themselves in the same boat.
The plugin was not installed along with docker.  Here is a one-liner:

```
sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest/download/docker-compose-$(uname -s | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')-$(uname -m) -o /usr/bin/docker-compose && sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/docker-compose && docker-compose --version.
```

Comment: This should really be a part of AL2023